# Preview links and "View as Web Page" Solutions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, cloudpage

At my company, we need to send out preview links within the organization internally before a communication is sent out. In our past platform (MailChimp) the "View as Web Page" option allowed us to copy that link and if we updated the content, the link would show the updates upon refreshing the linked page. I would like to replicate that with Marketing Cloud.

I also am having trouble getting to the preview link from Marketing Cloud as of now. Meaning, I can only grab the "View as Web Page" link once I have sent an email to myself. As it only populates "%%view_email_url%%" in the editor and leads me to a blank webpage when I click "view as web page" in the preview tab.

My current workaround, is creating a Cloudpage (identical to final email) and having the email (using Ampscript) to pull the landing page content and feeding it into the email. This is working ok, but the formatting is a bit off. I would like to find a better method or sure-up this method at this time.

In summary, is there a better method to first, get to the "view as web page" other than sending an email to myself? Secondly, is there a way to create live updating preview links?

Answer (score 0):

For the View in Web page, please refer https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_view_email_as_web_page_link_in_html_paste_emails.htm&type=5

You can pull the send-time data from the send logging data extension when the content is viewed in an email. For shared content or content viewed in a web page, the AMPscript displays the most current content. Please refer below link.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/sendTimeContent.htm

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but would this only apply once the email is sent? 

We have 20 separate branded versions of newsletters going out on a weekly basis, so sending 20 emails to myself to grab the "view as a web page" link is a bit tedious at this juncture. 

However, as I'm new to Marketing Cloud/AMPscript as a whole, I'm unsure.

Thanks!